# How to print the distance between two neighbors in a graph in Python

Tags: python, graph

I built a graph using a text file and it looks like this when I print:

```
{'Luebeck': [('Hamburg', '63')], 
 'Hannover': [('Hamburg', '153')], 
 'Bremen': [('Hamburg', '116')], 
 'Hamburg': [('Luebeck', '63'), ('Bremen', '116'), ('Hannover', '153')]}
```

I want to use the distance between two nodes, like between Luebeck & Hamburg (63) and I don't know how to get this value. Here is the code where I am using "graph[current][neighbor]" to get the cost between current and neighbor.

```
while not queue.empty():
    node = queue.get()
    current = node[1][len(node[1]) - 1]

    if end in node[1]:
        print("Path found: ")
        break

    cost = node[0]
    for neighbor in graph[current]:
        temp = node[1][:]
        temp.append(neighbor)
        queue.put((cost + graph[current][neighbor], temp))
```

It is showing following error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Could someone please help?

thanks

Comment: Probably either `current` or `neighbor` in `graph[current][neighbor]` is not a number. Print both of them before executing the last line.

Comment: yes they both are not numbers. their values are: Luebeck and 
('Hamburg', '63')

Comment: so you found your problem: `('Hamburg', '63')`  :)

Comment: So, the additional incurred cost is `neighbor[1]`, not `graph[current][neighbor]`.

Answer (score 0):

After changing this line, its working fine

```
queue.put((cost + int(neighbor[1]), temp))
```